# Python error using zipfile: 'list' object has no attribute 'tell'

Tags: python, list, zip, attributeerror, tell

I'm trying to zip up only *.csv files in a directory with this code:

```
allFiles = os.listdir( dirName + apt + '/' )
csvList  = [i for i in allFiles if i.endswith('.csv')]
zf       = zipfile.ZipFile([ dirName + apt + '.zip' ], mode='w')
for f in csvList:
    a    = dirName + apt + '/' + f
    zf.write( a )
#all the elements of a are strings
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-43-ebf4dc807b56>", line 1, in <module>
zf.write(a)
File "C:\Users\blevy\MCR\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\zipfile.py", line 1347, in write
zinfo.header_offset = self.fp.tell()    # Start of header bytes

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

Is there a simple fix to this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile([ dirName + apt + '.zip' ], mode='w')
```

should be:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(dirName + apt + '.zip', mode='w')
```

This is because [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) takes a file name, not a list of file names.

Comment: The contents of dirName + apt + '.zip' form a string.  The string, dirName', has the '/' characters, but this is a Windows machine that I'm using.  Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @BenjaminLevy:  Doesn't help.  You have `[` and `]` around your file name.  That makes it a list.  `ZipFile` doensn't take a list - it takes a single file name.  You need to remove the brackets.

Comment: Well, duh on me.  I'll try it and write back.  Tx.

Comment: Thanks, Gerrat.  Your advice worked.  My matlab training of using [ str + str] to concatenate strings tripped me up.  I could not see the error in Python.

Comment: that looks like a stupid typo but it happened to me when passing a list instead of the list first element... googling the error message landed here. Thanks